# Webpack 2 resolve alias

Tags: import, webpack, alias, resolve

I have a little problem regarding resolving aliases in webpack 2. No matter what i do i cant resolve this. Here is the relevant code:

```
/* webpack.mix.js */

       mix.webpackConfig({
         module: {
               rules: [
                   {
                       test: /\.js$/,
                       loader: 'eslint-loader'
                   }
               ]
           },
           resolve: {
             root: path.resolve(__dirname), 
                    // path is reqired at the beggining of file 
             alias: {
               config: 'src/assets/js/config', // this is a config folder
               js: 'src/assets/js'
             }
           }
       });

/* router.js */ 

        import { DashboardRoute } from 'config/route-components'
      // this import is unresolved
```

Answer (score 3):

The `resolve.root` option no longer exists in webpack 2. Instead it is merged into [`resolve.modules`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules) (from the official [Migration Guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#resolve-root-resolve-fallback-resolve-modulesdirectories)). Webpack even throws an error that it's not a valid property. If you want to be able to import from your root directory you would change the resolve config to:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    config: 'src/assets/js/config',
    js: 'src/assets/js'
  },
  modules: [
    path.resolve(__dirname),
    'node_modules'
  ]
}
```

Alternatively you can use an absolute path in your `resolve.alias` like so:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    config: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/js/config'),
    js: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/js')
  }
}
```

Comment: tnx a lot for your answer.
I'm having the same issue but for some strange reason the aliases don't work for me.
When I try to import using aliases I get: 
Unable to resolve path to module 'Components/pages/Master'
Unable to resolve path to module 'Styles/main.css'

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
resolve: {
  root: [
    'node_modules',
    path.resolve('src') // Resolve on root first
  ], 
  alias: {
    config: 'src/assets/js/config', // this is a config folder
    js: 'src/assets/js'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In ionic 3 (version 3.13.3), in order to get alias mapping working, you will have to define path mapping both in `webpack.config.js` & `tsconfig.json`

Please refer complete answer here [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46899829/905915)