# How to run a copy command in Ionic2 build script

Tags: ionic2, build-process, npm-scripts

I am trying to copy a single file from the src location to the "www" output folder. I then want to incorporate this into the build process so that after all the core build scripts are run, it runs my command.

I am following the [examples](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts#command-line-flags) in the App Build Scripts for Ionic. Basically I have:

Added a new config file with my command (as per this [example](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/blob/master/config/copy.config.js)): config\webpack_rj.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
    copyIndexContent: {
        src: ['{{SRC}}/web.config'],
        dest: '{{WWW}}'
    }
}
```

In my package.json I have added:

```json
"config": {
  "pwa_copy_webconfig": "./config/webpack_rj.config.js"
},
```

This is the part I do not understand - how to actually run it when I run the normal build process.

I have tried added an additional "scripts" entry in the package.json:

```json
"build": "ionic-app-scripts build ./config/webpack_rj.config.js",
```

However this did not work. So how can I invoke `copyIndexContent` or `pwa_copy_webconfig` from the build process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add a new step to the build process instead of extending copy. This is not possible unless you make custom changes to the app scripts module to take the `pwa_copy_webconfig` command from the config.

A common way is to extend the existing config file.
You can extend the `copy.config.js` in your `webpack_rj.config.js` file.

```js
const copyConfig = require('path_to_default_copy_config');
copyConfig.copyIndexContent.src.push('{{SRC}}/web.config');
```

In package.json add:

```json
"config": {
  "ionic_copy": "./config/webpack_rj.config.js"
},
```

Credit to [Raj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4695064/raj)'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43917890/4826457) for a different app script configuration.

Comment: Excellent, that's exactly what I needed and a great solution, thanks

Comment: One question - where does the name of the config come in -e.g. "ionic_copy". If I change this to something else it does not execute. How is it related to the build process?

Comment: it's the commands provided in the script to override specific configuration files. Check the section on override configuration files in the github readme

Comment: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/blob/master/README.md#overriding-config-files

Comment: FYI, here's the value I used for the somewhat vague string `path_to_default_copy_config`:

`../node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/config/copy.config.js`