# Controlling Webpack 3 Bundling / Chunking (in Ionic3)

Tags: webpack, ionic3, bundling-and-minification, chunking

I have a bunch of stuff in node_modules that, from what I can tell, all ends up in `vendor.js` when I build my Ionic3 project. For simplicity's sake, lets say I have the following folders in node_modules: abc, xyz, uvw, and qrs. Lets say further that abc and xyz are public libraries but uvw and qrs are private libraries. As such, I would like to end up not with a single `vendor.js` that includes all four libraries. Rather, I would like to end up with a `vendor.js` that includes abc and xyz, and a `private.js` that includes uvw and qrs.

How do I alter the configuration files in my Ionic3 project to achieve that outcome? Ideally I would only have to name uvw and qrs in the configuration and have the default behavior of vendor.js being generated for 'everything else' in node_modules.

**UPDATE**
For reference, Ionic 3.9.2 uses Webpack 3.10.0, and the default Ionic webpack config looks like the following. I really only care about the production build doing the behavior I describe above.

```
/*
 * The webpack config exports an object that has a valid webpack configuration
 * For each environment name. By default, there are two Ionic environments:
 * "dev" and "prod". As such, the webpack.config.js exports a dictionary object
 * with "keys" for "dev" and "prod", where the value is a valid webpack configuration
 * For details on configuring webpack, see their documentation here
 * https://webpack.js.org/configuration/
 */

var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ionicWebpackFactory = require(process.env.IONIC_WEBPACK_FACTORY);

var ModuleConcatPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/ModuleConcatenationPlugin');
var PurifyPlugin = require('@angular-devkit/build-optimizer').PurifyPlugin;

var optimizedProdLoaders = [
  {
    test: /\.json$/,
    loader: 'json-loader'
  },
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: [
      {
        loader: process.env.IONIC_CACHE_LOADER
      },

      {
        loader: '@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/webpack-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: true
        }
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    test: /\.ts$/,
    loader: [
      {
        loader: process.env.IONIC_CACHE_LOADER
      },

      {
        loader: '@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/webpack-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: true
        }
      },

      {
        loader: process.env.IONIC_WEBPACK_LOADER
      }
    ]
  }
];

function getProdLoaders() {
  if (process.env.IONIC_OPTIMIZE_JS === 'true') {
    return optimizedProdLoaders;
  }
  return devConfig.module.loaders;
}

var devConfig = {
  entry: process.env.IONIC_APP_ENTRY_POINT,
  output: {
    path: '{{BUILD}}',
    publicPath: 'build/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: ionicWebpackFactory.getSourceMapperFunction(),
  },
  devtool: process.env.IONIC_SOURCE_MAP_TYPE,

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json'],
    modules: [path.resolve('node_modules')]
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: process.env.IONIC_WEBPACK_LOADER
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    ionicWebpackFactory.getIonicEnvironmentPlugin(),
    ionicWebpackFactory.getCommonChunksPlugin()
  ],

  // Some libraries import Node modules but don't use them in the browser.
  // Tell Webpack to provide empty mocks for them so importing them works.
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  }
};

var prodConfig = {
  entry: process.env.IONIC_APP_ENTRY_POINT,
  output: {
    path: '{{BUILD}}',
    publicPath: 'build/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: ionicWebpackFactory.getSourceMapperFunction(),
  },
  devtool: process.env.IONIC_SOURCE_MAP_TYPE,

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json'],
    modules: [path.resolve('node_modules')]
  },

  module: {
    loaders: getProdLoaders()
  },

  plugins: [
    ionicWebpackFactory.getIonicEnvironmentPlugin(),
    ionicWebpackFactory.getCommonChunksPlugin(),
    new ModuleConcatPlugin(),
    new PurifyPlugin()
  ],

  // Some libraries import Node modules but don't use them in the browser.
  // Tell Webpack to provide empty mocks for them so importing them works.
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  }
};


module.exports = {
  dev: devConfig,
  prod: prodConfig
}
```

Comment: What is your ionic-app-scripts version?

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari as per the ./node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/package.json file for my project, version is 3.1.9; and it is possible, certainly to extend the Ionic webpack config ala https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41512923/how-to-extend-default-webpack-config-in-ionic-v2

Answer (score 3):

If you're using webpack v4, then `optimization.splitChunks.cacheGroups` is what you're looking for. Full doc [here](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/).

Now looks like OP want to manually pick what module goes to what bundle. This is how you can do it:

1. Add two new cacheGroups, say `optimization.splitChunks.cacheGroups.vendor` and `.private`
2. Set `filename`, `enforce` and `test` fields

```
cacheGroups.vendor = {
  filename: 'vendor.js',
  enforce: true,
  test: (module) => {
    const vendorList = ['abc', 'xyz']
    return vendorList.includes(module.name)
  }
}

// Similar config for `cacheGroups.private`
```

Comment: As it turns out, webpack version 3.10.0 goes with Ionic 3.9.2... does that change things?

Comment: I've updated the question with Ionic 3.9.2's default webpack config for reference.

Comment: is there a similar capability for webpack 3?

Comment: @vicatcu webpack 3 I'm not sure, I know `commonChunkPlugin` exist but not entirely sure I understand how it works. You can't even find doc for v3 on the official site now. [This](https://webpack-3.cdn.bcebos.com/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/) is a mirror to v3 doc.